# OCR is not working until Google Translator is Installed

Tags: android, android-vision

I have a problem using the Mobile Vision API.  I installed my app and is working in almost all the devices.  But when I try to install on some devices the text is not being recognized.  I try to clean the data and cache from Google Play Services and from my App, trying to update GPS and reinstall my app and doesn't work.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
```

I have this on my gradle.

When I install Google Translator and download the offline translation it works on this app and my app start to work.

Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: Most of the time, it's a Device related issue. ANd if you want to find out the problelem, you can use Loggers. Which you can read it from here -> https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the first time the application is running in a "new" device automatically downloads a library to scan the text, barcodes, face detection any feature on Mobile Vision API.  So the we need to have an internet connection the first time is running on our smartphone and it will be working properly.